# Laravel - Get Data from two tables using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables as per below structures:

**news_categories**

[image]

**news**

[image]

I need data to be displayed as below:

Major Events of year 2017

```
News1 Title
News1 desc

News2 Title
News2 desc

News3 Title
News3 desc
```

Major Events of year 2018

```
News1 Title
News1 desc

News2 Title
News2 desc

News3 Title
News3 desc
```

Major Events of year 2019

```
News1 Title
News1 desc

News2 Title
News2 desc
```

I have tried below query query but it return one record per category:

```
$grouped = NewsCategory::with(['news' => function($query){
    $query->groupBy('cat_id');
}])->get();
```

Comment: why do you need to  $query->groupBy('cat_id')? are you using some aggregation functions?

Comment: Nop.. just trying different stuff

Comment: try to make it `$grouped = NewsCategory::with('news')->get()`

Comment: lol.. so easy .. oops.. sometimes simple things work :)